# Is it possible to load all Zend_Form_Element_* with one statement?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I'd like to load several form elements like `Zend_Form_Element_Text` with one statement. Is there a way to do this with a `*` wild card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to load them like that, why don't you register Zend's autoloader?

> After registering the Zend Framework autoload callback, you can reference classes from Zend Framework without having to load them explicitly. The autoload() method uses Zend_Loader::loadClass() automatically when you reference a class.

All you need to put in your code is:

```
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

Quote is from http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.load.html

Comment: Thanks, just a note, I got a notice that `registerAutoload` is deprecated as of 1.8.0 so I used `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` as per this blog http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend_loaders-autoloader_deprecated-in-zend-framework-18/

Comment: Indeed, this is the better way to load classes